# Entity Framework fails to save the JSON objects after deserialization

Tags: json, json.net, entity-framework-6

I am developing a console application for fetching JSON objects from an Http Request. After fetching the JSON objects, it is deserialized into the local objects. After the deserialization, these data will be saved into the database. I am using Entity Framework for saving these objects into the database. But the problem is saving is failed in some cases and when fails, the below exception is thrown, which I can't understand. Here only the inner exception is shown.

> ex.InnerException
>
> {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HResult: -2146233087
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: {"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
>       Message: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>       Source: "EntityFramework"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at Syst
>   em.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__31.MoveNext()"
>       StateEntries: Count = 1
>       TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}

Can anyone please let me know why this problem is happening?

Comment: "String or binary data would be truncated" means one of your fields isn't big enough.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thank you very much for your comment. You are absolutely right. Two of the field size is not big enough to contain the data.